# Railties - When to use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

After reading some posts about the railties, I've didn't understand if i should only create railsties for gem/plugins that direct interfere with the rails initialization (e.g. create a generator, change some configuration) or if I should also use it for gem/plugins that only add functionality to rails (e.g. include some module in ActionView::Base or ActiveRecordBase).

Any idea or suggestion about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do both and more with railties.  There are hooks that a railtie can implement that would create a generator or do something on rails boot up.  People also use railties to ship rails specific gems.  They don't really "direct interfere" (as you said), they insert themselves in a initialization chain.  You can read more about [the init chain here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html).  Item 2.10 is where the custom railties (ie: your code) gets invoked (at least for startup).